# qemu/virt-manager no permisson on shared folder

Tags: qemu, shared-storage, 9p

I have a strange problem. Iam trying to create a shared folder via the add-hardware->filesystem option. For Type and Modus i choose Passtrought and for Driver Path. The Source Path is /free and target is mytag. 
I mount it with: mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio mytag /mnt/test -oversion=9p2000.L
Everything worked without problems. But when i enter /mnt/test and do a ls, i get "ls: Öffnen von Verzeichnis . nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung" in english something like "ls: cant open folder . no permission"

I set permissions of /free to 777 recursivly but nothing changed. Also tried some other modes in virt-manager but nothing changes. Do you have any clues, what i am doing wrong?

The guest-os ist Ubuntu 12.04 and the host-os is Ubuntu 11.10

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not much of a help - but this question on SO is asking a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511489/how-to-set-folder-permissions-for-a-kvm-9p-filesystem-share

Comment: Other similar questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/559726/kvm-guest-cannot-write-to-9p-share-owned-by-non-root and https://serverfault.com/questions/342801/read-write-access-for-passthrough-9p-filesystems-with-libvirt-qemu

Answer (score 1):

You asked for *any hints*, so here we go.

1. First, -orw in the mount options can help,
2. furthermore the user and group ids should match on both systems (they likely do if you use general users like ftp, www-data etc.)
3. check under which user the vm is started (e.g. kvm or libvirt-qemu - see /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf).
4. apparmor can create closed doors, too, there is various stackoverflow questions and posts on this.